# How do I extend a middle file system using only FDISK?

Tags: rhel

I just added additional 100gb to /dev/sda on vSphere client and need to add to /dev/sda2.  How?

```
#df -H

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda5        12G  1.9G  8.9G  18% /

tmpfs            13G     0   13G   0% /dev/shm

/dev/sda2        46G   28G   17G  64% /acs

/dev/sda1       199M   84M  106M  45% /boot

/dev/sda9       2.3G  3.6M  2.2G   1% /home

 /dev/sda3        29G  1.3G   26G   5% /secure

/dev/sda10      2.3G  1.7G  501M  77% /tmp

/dev/sda6       6.8G  2.6G  3.9G  41% /var

/dev/sda7       5.6G  3.5G  1.9G  66% /var/log/audit

/dev/sdb1       106G   14G   87G  14% /acs/apps/Program/pw/dbarchive
```

=====

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 221.2 GB, 113816633344 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13837 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009c915

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sda1   *           1          26      204800   83  Linux

Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.

/dev/sda2              26        5690    45493248   83  Linux

/dev/sda3            5690        9229    28432384   83  Linux

/dev/sda4            9229       13838    37017600    5  Extended

/dev/sda5            9230       10645    11372544   83  Linux

/dev/sda6           10646       11495     6823936   83  Linux

/dev/sda7           11495       12203     5686272   83  Linux

/dev/sda8           12203       13272     8584192   82  Linux swap / Solaris

/dev/sda9           13272       13555     2274304   83  Linux

/dev/sda10          13555       13838     2270208   83  Linux
```

Comment: Can you view this as **replacing** /dev/sda2 with a new 100GB, rather than **adding**? If you can it will make your life much simpler, you just use `fidsk` to make the new partition at the end, create a filesystem on it, mount the new fs (e.g. at /mnt), copy everything from /acs to /mnt, and then alter fstab to mount /dev/sda11 instead of /dev/sda2. The downside is it does leave a 46GB unused hole in your disk.  The advantages are it will take very little effort on your part to implement this solution.

Comment: Good Ideas and pointer Icarus,  I inherited the build and cleaning up the environment before I can build a case for an overhaul.  I would've prefer system partition be separated from application and tools partition.  Doesn't SDA11 have to be logical and at end of EXTENDED (sda4)?
SDA11 will also require I re-install my apps or correct paths, scripts and pointers.

Comment: sda11 does have to be logical, you already have your 4 primary partitions.  This is not anything to worry about. The mbr format has an array with 4 entries in it for the primary partitions, and then the logical partitions form a linked list so you can have lots of them. You will **not** have to reinstall anything if you mount /dev/sda11 onto either /acs (or /secure) provided you copied everything from /acs onto /dev/sda11. These approaches are minimal work for you at a cost of leaving a 46GB hole behind and only getting a 100GB /acs rather than a 146GB /acs. Can you afford this cost?

Comment: I had to mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda11 to resolve bad block issue.
To copy (cp -pr /acs /dev/sda11), do I have to umount/mount /acs or /dev/sda11?

Comment: Got it! copied from old to new partition (cp /dev/sda2 /dev/sda11) but it got swatted down here :(. I have to move my database to sda11 and link its directory in sda2 to point to new location in sda11.

Comment: You want to first do a `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda11` again (as you have copied the filesystem header which will say it is a 46GB size, rather than a 100GB), then mount /dev/sda11, e.g. on /mnt, then use `cp -pr /acs /mnt`, hopefully whilst nothing is writing to /acs. Then you umount both /acs and /mnt, then you edit /etc/fstab to change sda2 to sda11, and finally you mount /acs. `df` at that stage should show you the larger /acs.

Comment: Icarus, thanks for your time, patience and support!  I got it done and here is the final solution:

1.  Used "cfdisk to create sda11 size is 107GB

2.  Reboot system

3.  mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda11

4.  stop application and rename db directory

5.  create a new db directory in /

6.  mount /dev/sda11 to new db directory (Size is 107GB)

7.  cp old db to new db directory

8.  create symbolic link at old db directory location

Application started without any issue.
Application continue to exist in /acs less 13GB or previous size.
Database is moved to /dev/sda11 using 15% of 107GB.

Comment: Great, let me write it up as an answer, as comments can be deleted. If you edit `/etc/fstab` to mount /dev/sda11 on /acs you will not need steps 5, 6, and 8. I hope you see that if you can live with the limitations this is a lot simpler than moving the partitions around, particularly as you need to move the root filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

`fdisk` alone can not do this, it can resize/create new partitions but you will need to use other tools to move sda3-sda10 filesystems further down the disk and another tool to expand the sda2 filesystem. You're going to have your server off and be in a live OS regardless due to the fact that your root partition is sda5 and has to be moved. I would highly recommend using [gparted live cd/usb](http://gparted.sourceforge.net). It has an very easy to use UI and helps prevent any accidents. A cool feature of gparted live is that is shows you all the commands it runs to resize, move and expand. So in theory if you REALLY wanted to know how to do it all at the CLI yourself you could reverse engineer it.

Comment: Hi Zachary,  Thanks for your response.  I'm in a very control environment and it will take months/yrs to add new tool to the environment.  All I have now is cfdisk and fdisk.  I have tried moving sda3-sda10 to end of disk and each time my OS went into panic and had to restore.

Comment: Here is a good document on [how to do it all by hand](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_resizing_ext3_partitions). Hopefully your distro includes those utilities.

Comment: Good doc Zachary but I'm out of luck with the utilities/rpm. :(

Comment: Got it!  copied from old to new partition (cp /dev/sda2 /dev/sda11) but it got swatted down here :(.  I have to move my database to sda11 and link its directory in sda2 to point to new location in sda11.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to a slightly different problem. Rather than increase the size of an existing partition which involves moving most of the other partitions, instead just create a new partition and move the data.

The advantages are that this is simpler, and can be done with minimal downtime. The principle disadvantage is that you are leaving behind some unused disk space.

1. Use `cfdisk` to create a new partition `/dev/sda11`
2. Use `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda11` to create the filesystem on the partition
3. Mount the partition using `mount /dev/sda11 /mnt`
4. stop application
5. copy files from old location, `cd /acs ; cp -rp . /mnt`
6. unmount both copies, `cd / ; umount /acs ; umount /mnt`
7. edit `/etc/fstab` to mount `/dev/sda11` on `/acs`
8. Mount the new copy, `mount /acs`
9. Start the application

At some time in the future the `/dev/sda2` partition can be re-purposed.